# sum for nullable field in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this linq query

```
(from diference in General.db.PTStbDifferenceByMonths 
 join list in General.db.PTStbLists on new
  {
     month = diference.ListMonth,
     year = diference.ActiveYear,
     national = diference.NationalCode,
     shobe = diference.BranchCode
  }
  equals new
  {
     month = list.Month,
     year = list.Year,
     national = list.NationalCode,
     shobe = list.ShobeCode
  }
  join hoghoughList in General.db.PTStbhogogMomayezs on new
  {
     melliCode = diference.MelliCode,
     national = diference.NationalCode,
     shobe = diference.BranchCode,
     serial = list.Id
  }
  equals new
  {
     melliCode = hoghoughList.MelliCode,
     national = hoghoughList.NationalCode,
     shobe = hoghoughList.ShobeCode,
     serial = hoghoughList.SerialList
  }
  join karmand in General.db.PTStbKarkonans on 
  hoghoughList.MelliCode equals karmand.MelliCode
  where diference.ListMonth == activeMonth && diference.ActiveYear == activeYear && 
  diference.NationalCode == id && diference.BranchCode == branchCode
  select new ReturnedDifference
  {
     Maliat = hoghoughList.FinalTax,
     ComputedMaliat = diference.ComputedMaliat,
     ComputedMoghayerat = diference.ComputedMoghayerat,
     hoghough = (hoghoughList.NGPTotalDaramadeMashmol ?? 0),
     ListId = diference.ListMonth,
     MelliCode = karmand.MelliCode,
     LastName = karmand.Family,
     Name = karmand.Name,
     PayedTax = diference.PayedTax,
     ActualPayedTax = hoghoughList.FinalTax
  }).OrderBy(l => l.MelliCode);
```

I want to sum **hoghoughList.NGPTotalDaramadeMashmol** and group by by other fields but hoghoughList.NGPTotalDaramadeMashmol didn't have Sum function because it's nullable long. is it a way to sum this value and group by other fields?

Comment: `Sum` would work with a collection of numbers, not on a single number. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve `hoghoughList.NGPTotalDaramadeMashmol` appears to be `Nullable<long>` not a collection or `List<Nullable<long>>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the coalesce `??` to treat the nullable as 0:

```
.Sum(v => (v.hoghoughList.NGPTotalDaramadeMashmol ?? 0))
```